# Piccoche - a coordination game

Tags: javascript, game, dom

Click the divs to remove them. Remove all div's in the shortest time and minimal clicks (to do). Code needs streamlining.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div {
width:30px;
height:30px;
background-color:blue;
position:fixed;
}

</style>

<script>

function init() {
var i;
count=10;
for (i=0;i<10;i++) with (document.getElementById('div'+i).style) {top=rInt()+'px';left=rInt()+'px';}
}

function update(n) {
document.getElementById('div'+n).style.display='none';
count--;
if (count==0) alert('all gone!');
}

function rInt() {
return Math.floor(Math.random()*200);
}

</script>
</head>
<body onload='init();'>

<div id='div0' onclick='update(0);'></div>
<div id='div1' onclick='update(1);'></div>
<div id='div2' onclick='update(2);'></div>
<div id='div3' onclick='update(3);'></div>
<div id='div4' onclick='update(4);'></div>
<div id='div5' onclick='update(5);'></div>
<div id='div6' onclick='update(6);'></div>
<div id='div7' onclick='update(7);'></div>
<div id='div8' onclick='update(8);'></div>
<div id='div9' onclick='update(9);'></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a To Do list:

*To Do*

Add timer,
Add 'missed click counter',
Colours,
Size,
Positions,
Number,
Streamline code into DOM format,
Score,
Play again

*Options*

Flashers,
Multi-size,
Movers,
Bonuses (double points, static, combos, chains),
Anti-bonuses (move, faster, half points, bombs)

Answer (score 4):

This is cleaner.  
added `<title>` for no HTML Errors W3C Markup Validator. 
changed CSS units px to em, for 100% W3C Mobile OK  
changed width to 20em (320px) for Mobile Viewport 
added mobile meta viewport for Google PageSpeed Insights 100% (less when target divs overlap)
Moved JS below HTML
Made count global
added `<div id="page">` to get misses
added `<div id="msg">` to replace alert
replaced CSS `div {` with `.target{`
changed div ids to d+index
created target array and init code instead of calling getElementById
added [CDATA[ to JS
added miss counter
added elapsed time
added "Again" button and function
removed function `rInt()`, was not worth the stack push and pop of calling another function.

While some might say the update() should be added by `EventListener`. When only one event is required `onclick` is easy, reliable, and more universally compatible.

W3C HTML Markup Validation Service HTML5: NO ERRORS
W3C HTML Markup Validation Service XHTML Basic 1.1: NO ERRORS
W3C CSS Validation Service: NO ERRORS
W3C mobileOK Checker: Perfect Score: 100%

Google's "Usability Assesment" PageSpeed Insights

- Mobile User Experience: Perfect Score: 100%
- Desktop User Experience: Perfect Score: 100%
- Mobile Speed: Perfect Score: Perfect Score: 100%
- Desktop Speed: Perfect Score: 100%

Yahoo's YSlow Grade Perfect Score: 100% (gtmetrix.com)
Page Speed Grade: 99% (gtmetrix.com) 1% loss due to bug in PageSpeed scoring
Page Load time 0.250 seconds (gtmetrix.com)

**HTML CSS**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title>Piccoche</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
.target {
width:1.8em;
height:1.8em;
background-color:blue;
position:fixed;
}
#page{width:20em;height:20em;background:#ff0;margin:0;padding:0;}
.hide{display:none;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" onclick="miss()">
<div id="msg" class="hide"><h3>All Gone!</h3><p id="score"></p><button onclick="playAgain()">Again</button></div>
<div id="d0" class="target" onclick="update(event,0)"></div>
<div id="d1" class="target" onclick="update(event,1)"></div>
<div id="d2" class="target" onclick="update(event,2)"></div>
<div id="d3" class="target" onclick="update(event,3)"></div>
<div id="d4" class="target" onclick="update(event,4)"></div>
<div id="d5" class="target" onclick="update(event,5)"></div>
<div id="d6" class="target" onclick="update(event,6)"></div>
<div id="d7" class="target" onclick="update(event,7)"></div>
<div id="d8" class="target" onclick="update(event,8)"></div>
<div id="d9" class="target" onclick="update(event,9)"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
count=10;
misses = 0;
var target = new Array;
var elapsed = new Date();
function init() {
  var ndx = 0;
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var div=0; div<divs.length; div++){
    did = divs[div].getAttribute("id");
    if (did != null){
      if (did.substring(0,1) == "d"){
        ndx = parseInt(did.substring(1,2));
        target[ndx] = divs[div];
        target[ndx].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*290) + 'px'
        target[ndx].style.left= Math.floor(Math.random()*290) + 'px';
        ndx++;
      }
    }
  }
} 
function miss(){misses++;}
function update(e,n) {
if(count == 10){elapsed = new Date();}
target[n].style.display='none';
count--;
if (count==0){
  var t = new Date();
  document.getElementById('msg').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Misses=' + misses + ' <br/>Elapsed time = ' + (t - elapsed)/1000  + ' Sec.';}
  if(e && e.stopPropagation){e.stopPropagation();}
  else{e.cancelBubble = true;}
}
window.onload = init;
//]]>
</script>
</body></html>
```

**New Play Again function**

```
function playAgain(){
  for (var div=0; div<10; div++){
    target[div].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*290) + 'px';
    target[div].style.left= Math.floor(Math.random()*290) + 'px';
    target[div].style.display = 'block';
  }
  count = 10;
  misses = -1;
  elapsed = new Date();
  document.getElementById('msg').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: looks good. can you put it in a snippet/jsfiddle. why use <div id="page" onclick="miss()">, can we use <div id="page" onclick="misses++;"> instead. what's the PageSpeed bug/

Comment: what does the echo do? and misses remains 0. i think i might to use setTimeout to make a dynamic timer. does code review have question page size limits, coz this could go on for a while.

Comment: echo is a typo, I did a PHP version also.  Then I deleted the PHP and missed that.  I just changed it so the clock starts ticking when the first tile is clicked.  have not save that edit yet.   I will remove the echo too.

Comment: the reason I went with calling function miss() is because I was expecting potential problem with bubbling.  this is where both the update() and miss() are called for the same click.  I was able to use stopPropagation() in the update routine to suppress bubbling.  So the onclick="misses++;" should be fine.

Comment: I wish I could favorite answers, I had no idea there were so many validators for looking at markup!

Comment: @Coburn There is also gtmetrix.com for PageSpeed and Yahoo's Yslow, Google Page Speed Insights, and WebPageTest `http://www.webpagetest.org/` which is the same as the gtmetrix PageSpeed but has a more technical interface with various options.  gtmetrix is easy and good report, webpagetest delivers a very detailed JSON file.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Piccoche</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<style type="text/css">
.target {
width:1.8em;
height:1.8em;
background-color:#f44;
position:fixed;
border:1px solid black;
}
#page {
width:19.5em;
height:19.5em;
background-color:#9d6;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border:3px solid black;
}
.hide {
text-align:center;
display:none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page" onclick="misses++;">
<div id="msg" class="hide">
<h3>All Gone!</h3>
<p id="score"></p>
<button onclick="playAgain()">Again</button>
</div>
<div id="d0" class="target" onclick="update(event,0)"></div>
<div id="d1" class="target" onclick="update(event,1)"></div>
<div id="d2" class="target" onclick="update(event,2)"></div>
<div id="d3" class="target" onclick="update(event,3)"></div>
<div id="d4" class="target" onclick="update(event,4)"></div>
<div id="d5" class="target" onclick="update(event,5)"></div>
<div id="d6" class="target" onclick="update(event,6)"></div>
<div id="d7" class="target" onclick="update(event,7)"></div>
<div id="d8" class="target" onclick="update(event,8)"></div>
<div id="d9" class="target" onclick="update(event,9)"></div>
</div>
<div id="time"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
count=10;
misses=0;
dynTime=setInterval('time.textContent=((new Date-elapsed)/1000).toFixed(1);',100);
var target=new Array;
var elapsed=new Date;
function init() {
  var ndx = 0;
  var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
  for (var div=0; div<divs.length; div++) {
    did = divs[div].getAttribute("id");
    if (did != null){
      if (did.substring(0,1) == "d"){
        ndx = parseInt(did.substring(1,2));
        target[ndx] = divs[div];
        target[ndx].style.top = Math.floor(Math.random()*18)+1 + 'em';
        target[ndx].style.left= Math.floor(Math.random()*18)+1 + 'em';
        ndx++;
      }
    }
  }
} 

function update(e,n) {
target[n].style.display='none';
count--;
if (count==0){
  clearInterval(dynTime);
  var t = new Date();
  document.getElementById('msg').style.display='block';
  str='Misses : ' + misses + ' <br/>Elapsed time : ' + (t - elapsed)/1000  + ' seconds';
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = str;}
  if(e && e.stopPropagation){e.stopPropagation();}
  else{e.cancelBubble = true;}
}
function playAgain(){
  for (var div=0; div<10; div++)
    with (target[div].style) {
        top = Math.floor(Math.random()*18)+1 + 'em';
        left= Math.floor(Math.random()*18)+1 + 'em';
        display = 'block';
  }
  count = 10;
  misses = -1;
  elapsed = new Date;
  document.getElementById('msg').style.display='none';
dynTime=setInterval('time.textContent=((new Date-elapsed)/1000).toFixed(1);',100);

}
window.onload = init;
//]]>
</script>
</body></html>
```

Tidied it up a bit, added dynamic timer (added current miss count should be a breeze). Gonna fix the div's up next. Made everything 'em' - *changed CSS units px to em, for 100% W3C Mobile OK* missed your +'px' in the code.

Comment: The px in the JS will not affect MobileOK, only the CSS width and height.  Mobile OK will not see the JS positioning.  When you are at 100% Mobile OK, that cannot be beat.  It is not easy to get 100%.  Mobile OK is the reason I check the HTML markup with XHTML Basic 1.1.  Any errors with that doctype will cost points.

Comment: i had a look at your SO profile - these guys need a forum : https://www.distribly.com/sell-pdfs.html @Misunderstood

Comment: The `with (divs[div].style) {` is cleaner. I like how you create the divs. While it makes the init routine much cleaner, the bad thing, it does not work. It is easier to go with the HTML divs. `addEventListener` does not work with older IE Browsers.('event' in quotes will get the event to fire. `misses,numdiv, and count` need `var `. If you want to have variable number of divs, consider using PHP to generate the HTML and JS. I find JS gets out of control when an apps HTML is not scripted. PHP can make a page functional, then use JS only for improving the look, and user interaction.